# PHP - How to configure SchemaUpdateOption to ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION in PHP BigQuery library

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am using the BigQuery PHP client library, however I cannot figure out how to configure the insertRows() function to ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION in order to allow dynamic additions of columns to the schema.

Is there somewhere to configure this?

I am unable to find any documentation on this.

The closest I could get was on this page, but it appears this is the only page that doesn't include PHP documentation -.-

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas

Wondering if its configured here

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
```

Or on a query or insertRows function...

```
query($query)->schemaUpdateOptions('ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION');
```

```
$table->insertRows([ ['data' => $data] ])->schemaUpdateOptions('ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema update options are supported only in **LOAD JOBS** and in two cases:

- when writeDisposition is `"WRITE_APPEND"`;
- when writeDisposition is `"WRITE_TRUNCATE"` and the destination table is a partition of a table, specified by partition decorators. For normal tables, `"WRITE_TRUNCATE"` will always overwrite the schema.

  Example:

> ```
> $query->schemaUpdateOptions([
>     'ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'
> ]);
> ```

Your insertRows method won't work with this, as that uses Streaming Inserts.